# Как загрузить изображение из памяти в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, picasso

Пробую с помощью Picasso загрузить файл из внутренней памяти по uri
Все время вылетает, дает ошибку 
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
Ошибка на строке .load(uri)
Вот мой код, помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.List;

import it.sephiroth.android.library.picasso.Picasso;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

    List<Cover> covers;

    RecyclerAdapter(List<Cover> covers) {
        this.covers = covers;
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView){
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Cover cover = covers.get(position);
        String filePath = String.valueOf(cover.getFileBookCover());
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cover URI URI: " + filePath);
        Uri uri = cover.getFileBookCover();

        Picasso
                .with(holder.itemView.getContext())
                .load(uri)
                .into((ImageView) holder.itemView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return covers.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cardView;
        ImageView imgObl;

        ViewHolder (View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            imgObl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_recycler_item);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.into((ImageView) holder.itemView);` - ошибка тут. надо написать `.into(holder.imgObl)`

Вы кидаете пикассо корень холдера, аон не является `ImageView`

И лучше в холдере сделайте паблик метод `bind()` туда передавайте `uri` и вызов пикассо пусть будет в этом методе.
а у адаптера в методе onBindViewHolder вызывайте `holder.bind(uri)`

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ImageViewHolder> {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "my_log";

List<Cover> covers;

RecyclerAdapter(List<Cover> covers) {
    this.covers = covers;
}
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView){
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Cover cover = covers.get(position);
    String filePath = String.valueOf(cover.getFileBookCover());
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cover URI URI: " + filePath);
    Uri uri = cover.getFileBookCover();
    holder.bind(uri);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return covers.size();
}

public static class ImageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private CardView cardView;
    private ImageView imgObl;

    ViewHolder (View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        imgObl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_recycler_item);
    }

    public void bind(Uri uri) {
        Picasso
                .with(itemView.getContext())
                .load(uri)
                .into(imgObl);   
    }
}
```

}

Comment: красит красным, не дает так писать

Comment: конечно ругается, вы же в OnBindViewHolder типом передаете не свой ViewHolder класс, а базовый из ресайлера. у него поля imgObl нету.

Comment: extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> - вот так сделайте. и вообще свои классы не стоит называть так же как базовые. запутаетесь. лучше назовите ImageViewHolder

Comment: @Вячеслав дополнил ответ полным кодом

Comment: Все работает, спасибо!